# Error on executing partner center powershell

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication, getmodulefilename

We referenced below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/overview?view=partnercenterps-3.0#other-microsoft-powershell-modules

And then, we execute below powershell command with our csp partner center account.
But we got error on getting information of customer tenant.

Do we miss something? How can we resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80DOR.png)

Install-Module -Name PartnerCenter -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers
import-module PartnerCenter
Get-Module
Connect-PartnerCenter

#Connect-PartnerCenter -UseDeviceAuthentication
#$credential = Get-Credential
#Connect-PartnerCenter -Credential $credential -Tenant 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' -ServicePrincipal

Get-PartnerCustomer -domain 'xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'

[error]

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PartnerCustomer -domain 'xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
Get-PartnerCustomer : {"code":10001,"description":"Authentication failed. MFA required.","data":[],"source":"PartnerApiServiceControllers"}
위치 줄:1 문자:1

- Get-PartnerCustomer -domain 'xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-PartnerCustomer], PartnerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Commands.GetPartnerCustomer
  ```

Comment: The error says: `MFA required.` so you need to get a proper auth token. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/multi-factor-auth?view=partnercenterps-3.0).

Comment: you just need to authenticate with an account that has MFA enabled

Comment: MFA is already applied.  But , when we run "Connect-PartnerCenter" , only asked account and password  and we got "Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab."  in web browser. The MFA option is not triggerd. But we got return value Account, Enviroment and TenaItntId.  It seems like pass the Authentication normally.